# PHP how to add link to resources use klein.php

Tags: php

I'm writing a training app using basic PHP and routing klain.php I have a problem. How to connect to own css/js here. How to set the path to CSS and js, because routing klain.php blocks all park paths.

I use this but not work:

```
$klein->respond('/css/main.css', function ($request, $response, $service) {
    $response->file('/css/main.css');
});
```

When launched, it downloads the file to the hard drive.

Comment: Am not familiar with Klein, but that's most likely because the `content-type` header is either missing or not set to `text/css` (use browser development tools, or `curl -I` to investigate/confirm). _However_ requests for serving static assets shouldn't reach php at all, serving them via php is not a good practice, and certainly not something to encourage - it adds unnecessary complexity to the process - the web server (apache, nginx, iis) should take care of that directly. Are you following a tutorial, or writing one for others to follow? or other?